# How to generate buttons programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to generate buttons on a view using a loop .
suppose I want to generate 3 buttons. I have added a uiview btnframe to my main view. now I want to add button inside that view using that view's coordinates. how do I calculate btnframe's bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well what size do you want your buttons to be?  If you add them to a view they inherit those cordinates so if you do 0,0 it will be in the top left corner of the view you add it to.

```
for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,20 * x,100,20);
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[btnframe addSubview:button];
.....
}
```

The basics, this would give you three buttons.

If you want a grid something like this would work.

```
for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<5;y++){
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x * 100, y * 20, 100, 20)];
        [button setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",x,y]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [mainView addSubview:button];
    }
}
```

This gives you 25 buttons, 5 on each row.

Comment: i want to generate something like a grid view with each button leads to a new view